# Methods with "With" prefix?

Tags: design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

I started working on a project and I saw some methods with this `With` prefix and I'm wondering if this refers to a known pattern.

Does anyone know of this naming pattern?

Comment: Could you provide some examples? I’ve seen methods with a With prefix used in a Fluent Builder Pattern, but even then only use it when it makes sense.

Comment: @RikD I saw 2 sub-patterns: A) methods that returns `void` and simply set fields (essentially setters); and B) methods that set fields and returns `this`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen a `with` prefix used in a couple of different ways that may be similar to what's being done in the codebase you're working on.

### [Joshua Bloch's Builder pattern](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)

```
var myobj = MyObj.builder()
        .withProperty1("property 1 value")
        .withProperty2("property 2 value")
        .build();
```

### Clone immutable objects

```
var myImmutableObj = new MyImmutableObj("property 1 value", "property 2 value");
var myImmutableObjClone = myImmutableObj.withProperty1("different property 1 value");
```

Comment: Very interesting, I think they are using both approaches in this project. You nailed it, thanks!

Comment: To be clear, this is [Joshua Bloch's Builder Pattern](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2). Not the [GoF Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: @candied_orange are both of them called "builder pattern"?

Comment: @underthevoid yes. So much so that I never just say builder pattern anymore without qualifying. So much so that I nag other people about it. I hate names that require disambiguation. So much that it can make me fail to upvote an otherwise decent answer while I wait for an edit.

Comment: I don't understand. Just edit the answer if you feel the disambiguation is so necessary!

Comment: @svidgen didn't want to be hasty and start an edit war. But Mike's been gone for 6 hours now. So...

Comment: @candied_orange Hopefully folks aren't so offended by a minor edit that it turns into *any* sort of war ... but, fair enough.